# $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ then either $N_G(M)=M$ or $N_G(M)=G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ then either $N_G(M)=M$ or $N_G(M)=G$.

Recall that

- $N_G(M)=\{g\in G | gM=Mg\}$
- A proper subgroup $M$ of $G$ is called maximal if whenever $M\leq H \leq G$, either $H=M$ or $H=G$.

I think I am overthinking this but let's just make sure. So

By the definition of maximal, it is enough to show $M \leq N_g(M) \leq G$. Well isn't this statement trivial? If not, why?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in what you've written. Perhaps the most nontrivial thing to prove is that $N_G(M)$ is indeed a group

Comment: Yes, you are overthinking it. By definition, $N_G(M)$ will always contain $M$, so you always have $M\leq N_G(M)\leq G$.

Comment: @Teddy38 Then why is this an exercise in Dummit & Foote?!?!   Grrrr.

Comment: Because you need to prove it is a subgroup that contains $M$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Again isn't that trivial? Since by def, I can rewrite the condition of $N_G(M)$, as $M=g^{-1}Mg$ which after manipulation gives me the condition $g^{-1}h\in M$ where $h\in M$

Comment: Yes, it’s easy. That doesn’t mean it shouldn’t be an exercise. Not every exercise needs to be difficult, just like not every run needs to be a marathon.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But I can say trivially, $N_G(M)\leq G$?

Comment: You can say trivially that $N_G(M)\subseteq G$. The subgroup result isn't trivial.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown I suppose the others are right, the main difficulty is showing that normalisers are actually subgroups. But then that's not too tricky either.

Comment: Reading your penultimate comment to me, I don't think you've got the fact that it is a subgroup down. What you write is false (if it were true that $gM=Mg$ implies $g^{-1}h\in M$ for $h\in M$, you would be proving that $N_G(M)$ is *contained* in $M$, which is not true in general). So perhaps you need to very carefully prove that $N_G(M)$ is in fact a subgroup of $G$: what you propose is incorrect and doesn't do it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I wrote up what I have. Let me know if there are any gaps in my logic.

Comment: The gap is in understanding what is actually at issue. It is *not* whether $M$ is a subgroup of $N_G(M)$ once you know $N_G(M)$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $M$. That’s *immediate*. The issue is to *prove* that $N_G(M)$ is a subgroup that contains $M$.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof:** Assume $M$ is maximal subgroup of $G$. Then $M\leq H\leq G$, for some $H\leq G$, implies $H=M$ or $H=G$. We need to show that $N_G(M)=H$.

*Facts:*

- If $M$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $M\subseteq N_G(M)$.
- $N_G(M)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

What we are missing is that $M$ is a subgroup of $N_G(M)$. i.e. $x,y\in M \Rightarrow x^{-1}y\in M$. But we have this since $M$ is a group. Hence we can claim $H=N_G(M)$ which implies $N_G(M)=M$ or $N_G(M)=G$.

Comment: If you know that $N_G(M)$ is a subgroup of $G$, and you know $M$ is a subgroup of $G$ contained in $N_G(M)$, then you know $M$ is a subgroup of $N_G(M)$. The actual difficult part of this proposition is *actually proving* the two “facts” you list. (If $A\leq G$, $B\leq G$, and $A\subseteq B$, then because $A$ is a group with the induced operation of $B$, $A\leq B$. Your final paragraph is pablum)